# Inflating view does not apply proper attributes

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm a newbie working with Android and I'm having some problems with something which seems basic to me.

I have a fragment (*`MainFragment`*) inside of an activity (`MainActivty`). In MainFragment's `onCreateView` I inflate the MainFragment XML layout, which includes a `CardStackView` (a custom AdapterView) and set its adapter with a `CardStackAdapter` instance.

The problem comes when populating the `CardStackView`, as height properties are ignored. My goal is to include all the views within `CardStackView` centered both vertical and horizontal. I want to have a Card stack-alike effect (similar to Tinder UI, for instance).

**Java files**

*MainFragment.java*

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    CardStackView stackView = (CardStackView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cardStackView);

    CardStackAdapter adapter = new CardStackAdapter(this.getActivity(), stackView);
    adapter.add(createCard("name1", "age", 14, 21));
    adapter.add(createCard("name2", "age", 15, 21));
    adapter.add(createCard("name3", "age", 16, 21));

    stackView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return rootView;
}
```

*CardStackView.java*

```
public class CardStackView extends AdapterView<ListAdapter> {
    private ListAdapter adapter = null;

    public CardStackView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CardStackView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public ListAdapter getAdapter() {
        return adapter;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(ListAdapter listAdapter) {
        this.adapter = listAdapter;
        removeAllViewsInLayout();
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public View getSelectedView() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelection(int i) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

        if (adapter != null) {
            // Add children if we haven't added any yet
            if (getChildCount() == 0) {
                for (int index=0; index < adapter.getCount(); index++) {
                    View newChildView = adapter.getView(index, null, this);
                    addAndMeasureChild(newChildView, index);
                }
            }

            positionItems();
        }
    }

    private void positionItems() {
        int numOfElements = getChildCount();
        for (int index=0; index < numOfElements; index++) {
            View child = getChildAt(index);

            int width = child.getMeasuredWidth();
            int height = child.getMeasuredHeight();

            child.layout(0, 10*(numOfElements-index), width, height);
        }
    }

    private void addAndMeasureChild(View view, int index) {
        LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
        if (params == null) {
            params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        }

        // Index 0 inserts new child at the beginning of the list (thus rendering it at the back)
        addViewInLayout(view, 0, params, true);

        int itemWidth = getWidth();
        int itemHeight = getHeight();
        view.measure(MeasureSpec.EXACTLY | itemWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY | itemHeight);    
    }
}
```

*CardStackAdapter.java*

```
public class CardStackAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Card> cardsArray;
    private Context context;
    private ViewGroup containerView;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CardStackAdapter(Context c, ViewGroup containerView) {
        super();
        this.context = c;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
        this.containerView = containerView;
        this.cardsArray = new ArrayList<Card>();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        Card card = this.getItem(i);

        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false);
            view.setOnTouchListener(card);
        }

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false);
        ImageView mPicture = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.picture);
        TextView mName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView mLikes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.likes);
        TextView mDislikes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dislikes);

        mName.setText(card.getName());
        mLikes.setText(card.getLikes().toString());
        mDislikes.setText(card.getDislikes().toString());
        mPicture.setImageDrawable(card.getPicture());

        return view;
    }

    public void add(Card card) {
        cardsArray.add(card);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public Card getItem(int i) {
        return cardsArray.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return cardsArray.size();
    }
}
```

** Layout files **

*fragment_main.xml*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:text="Top text" />

    <jorgerdg.likeornot.CardStackView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:id="@+id/cardStackView"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#fffffec7"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:text="Top text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

*card_view.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="215dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/card_border"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:background="#ffd1ff7e"
        android:layout_weight="0.95"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:text="Yorch, 22"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="21"
            android:id="@+id/likes"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ff26ff00"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="13"
            android:id="@+id/dislikes"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffff0060"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

*card_border.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

** Screenshots **

This is what I'm getting:

[image: problem screenshot]

And this is what I'd like to get:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can try with

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, true);
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, true);
```

doing this, you attach that view to the parent extending the properties of that parent.